# Touchpad Fujitsu UH-X is not detected in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, grub2, 20.04, touchpad

I tried to install Ubuntu 20.04 dual boot with Windows 10 on My UH-X. I found that

1. The touchpad can work properly on Windows 10.
2. I run Ubuntu 20.04 kernel 5.10.4 and tried to check with xinput command. It's not shown the touchpad in the list.
   [xinput_Fujitsu UH-X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gcDp.png)
3. I tried to edit grub as the recommend in ask.ubuntu which they claimed that can solved this problem in previous medel but it's not work in UH-X.
   [grub editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Emx3c.png)

Please help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ubuntu 21.10 and Fujitsu Lifebook UH,

```
sudo modprobe i2c_hid
```

did not work, but

```
sudo modprobe i2c-hid-acpi
```

worked.

Answer (score 1):

That's what worked for me.

1. Load Terminal with Ctrl-Alt-T
2. sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
3. sudo reboot
4. sudo modprobe i2c_hid

It started working right after 4), not sure if steps 2 and 3 were even necessary. Also I have to run 4) every time I log in, adding it to start-up scripts doesn't work for some reason

Comment: Just running the 4th `modprobe` command is enough for Ubuntu 20.04.2

Comment: Well, they broke it completely in 21. I'm on 21.10 atm and there's just no way to revive the trackpad. I filed a bug in the Ubuntu bug tracker months ago, zero feedback so far

Comment: did u try `sudo modprobe i2c-hid-acpi` said by @user1544291

Comment: Also want to ask, is sleep mode working? my UH-X is U9311 btw

Comment: Yay! It works indeed. Thank you! I missed that answer. Sleep mode works, but only one way :) I close the lid, it goes to sleep and never comes back. Sometimes the screen flashes for a split second, but it never goes back to life completely

Comment: Love how intuitive it is: just start Terminal and run `sudo modprobe i2c-hid-acpi`. Couldn't have been easier. I really like Linux as long as I SSH into it, but desktop experience is still largely frustrating

Comment: Mine too screen flashes for a split second, and no wake

Comment: BeastOfCaerbannog's answer about adding i2c_hid to /etc/modules works for me - of course if I replace it with i2c-hid-acpi

Answer (score 0):

Insert this line in `/etc/modules`:

```
i2c_hid
```

That way, the module is launched at boot automatically.